# Burninate [development-environment]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[development-environment](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development-environment) has no tag wiki and only 8 questions, none of which seem related to each other.  Should we get rid of it?

(I'm vaguely aware that burninations are generally requested for tags with hundreds or thousands of questions, but I'm not familiar with the various processes for modifying or deleting tags, and I'm also not really sure when it's appropriate to request tag deletion, so I figured I would at least ask here before doing anything.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree to get rid of this tag. You could edit the 8 questions and remove the tag. If no questions are related to this tag, the tag will vanish.

Comment: Ok, I've removed from the remaining questions.  Looks like somebody else already edited some of the questions.